# Send Song path to mediaPlayer to play

Tags: android

I need to send Song info to default media player to play selected song from my app.

Is there any way to get Default music player object and pass song info to play.

I tried with MediaPlayer APi call.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();     
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.setDataSource(selectedItem.path); 
//mFile is the path to your mp3 file
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

With the above code, two songs start playing. One from the default music player and one from the player created by me.

Please help.

Comment: Please before posting any questions do a google search and try to identify the problem you are facing. Use below link for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

mpintro = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/intro.mp3"));
mpintro.setLooping(true);
mpintro.start();

Comment: If already song is playing from google music player and i try your code.I hear two songs playing.

Answer (score 0):

I am playing song from my app using below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, selectedItem.title);
startActivity(intent);
```